# who can help me uncompress the data?I cant deal with it

Tags: javascript, zip, gzip, zlib

```
var gzipcompresseddata=new Int8Array([120,156,237,87,93,111,155,48,20,125,110,165,254,7,228,31,16,62,178,180,123,0,36,66,12,65,50,4,129,163,173,79,22,16,7,101,3,202,40,168,233,191,159,13,88,165,157,52,181,219,67,165,8,158,238,185,199,215,220,175,35,132,30,219,145,23,98,243,230,250,74,247,119,27,136,188,192,217,113,36,224,198,212,180,187,149,46,11,212,83,248,62,132,156,209,229,209,234,189,54,178,226,152,1,245,43,59,47,64,207,184,187,221,134,3,69,151,133,217,251,99,124,143,120,248,237,82,151,133,205,51,145,95,165,162,251,22,134,145,103,33,169,74,74,106,0,76,207,100,29,18,167,107,136,77,124,47,112,29,24,184,196,141,241,119,226,107,43,85,65,27,151,40,96,204,105,143,144,153,38,217,79,150,17,55,123,231,6,121,110,128,77,90,37,105,65,117,121,132,3,5,67,188,117,246,129,45,29,187,42,51,64,65,127,117,73,1,228,9,251,45,242,48,52,219,166,227,161,47,142,225,128,231,56,251,24,74,141,1,148,133,210,63,64,202,167,32,157,128,241,214,56,132,44,55,43,250,88,148,229,175,61,24,224,15,190,106,235,5,1,140,99,83,16,172,239,194,53,45,128,248,86,216,59,174,116,24,88,107,36,234,29,193,192,216,91,139,69,34,62,85,97,14,4,11,150,218,231,154,141,74,59,0,233,169,73,106,3,52,180,166,73,11,164,242,84,151,28,243,251,128,116,60,21,45,101,21,176,89,67,43,98,195,12,89,44,25,16,144,186,166,48,0,48,91,122,110,187,134,62,202,79,15,15,7,162,104,170,182,248,81,231,108,73,198,28,217,24,222,100,173,179,137,110,49,219,140,119,213,129,246,108,137,172,192,30,199,166,174,38,189,20,32,157,130,196,0,234,226,118,218,216,151,102,168,239,105,70,86,36,101,253,247,94,252,89,125,90,147,35,91,249,140,148,167,42,63,210,42,39,249,99,123,38,37,95,249,226,144,147,98,81,87,175,186,242,182,9,156,27,132,244,175,170,82,103,85,93,174,170,150,179,170,62,71,85,218,172,170,203,83,85,125,202,184,65,84,77,153,133,245,73,194,90,206,194,186,60,97,245,159,43,85,253,114,55,171,234,191,85,197,6,47,126,255,110,174,127,3,92,166,143,255])

var blob=new Blob([gzipcompresseddata],{type:"application/zip"})
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a zlib stream, not a gzip stream.